# I try to get data from db and got nothing in codeigneiter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

my controller :

```
$ip = $this->input->ip_address();
$date= date("Ymd");
$online= time();
$ddd = array(
    'ip' => $ip,
    'date' => $tanggal,
    'online' => $online,
    'hits' => 1
);
$s = $this->Admin_models->cek_ip($ddd);
if (!$s){
    $s['hits'] = $s['hits'] + 1;
    $this->Admin_models->update_view($s);
}
```

my models :

```
public function cek_ip($data){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('ip =',$data['ip']);
    $this->db->where('date=',$data['date']);
    $this->db->from('statistikview');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() == 0){
        $this->db->insert('statistikview',$data);
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

public function update_view($data){
    $this->db->update('statistikview',$data);
    return true;
}
```

i try to get ip data from db if the ip data does exist and input all of the data to variable $s, but variable $s get nothing and all value become null, in my case i just wanna update db if the ip is exist

Comment: Your variable $s just contains a boolean value. Make `cek_ip` return the actual row.

Comment: @dontwannaknow return last inserted data in `cek_ip` function like `$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('id',$db->this->last_insert_id());
    $this->db->from('statistikview');
    $query = $this->db->get();`

Comment: @dontwannaknow You have not defined `$tanggal` in `$ddd array`

Comment: @dontwannaknow you can also replace this by `if (!$s){
    $d['hits'] = $ddd['hits'] + 1;
   $this->Admin_models->update_view($d);
}`
and you update query seems to be wrong. you didn't pass id with where condition.